# update mongodb with CSV data using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, csv, pymongo

i am trying to update mongodb with the data in csv file, my csv file contain columns like Ticket-ID, type, description etc.., if the document with same 'Ticket-ID' already exist in the collection i want to update the other columns of that 'Ticket-ID' in that document or else i want to insert a new document, i tried the below code

```
  def fix_dict(self,data, ignore_duplicate_key=True):


    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        list2 = list()
        for e in data:
            list2.append(self.fix_dict(e))
        # end if
        return list2
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        # end if
        for key, value in data.items():
            value = self.fix_dict(value)
            old_key = key
            if "." in key:
                key = old_key.replace(".", "")
                if key not in data:
                    data[key] = value
                else:
                    error_msg = "Dict key {key} containing a \".\" was ignored, as {replacement} already exists".format(
                        key=key_old, replacement=key)
                    if force:
                        import warnings
                        warnings.warn(error_msg, category=RuntimeWarning)
                    else:
                        raise ValueError(error_msg)
                    # end if
                # end if
                del data[old_key]
            # end if
            data[key] = value
        # end for
        return data
    # end if
    return data
# end def


def import_content(self,filename, Database, Collection):

    filepath = os.path.join(CurrentFilePath, filename)
    mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient()
    mongo_db = mongo_client[Database] 
    db_cm = mongo_db[Collection]

    data = pd.read_csv(filepath,encoding='utf-8-sig')
    datajson = data.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii = False)    
    data_json = json.loads(datajson)
    updatedata = self.fix_dict(data_json)
    for d in updatedata:
        print d['Ticket-ID']
        db_cm.update_many({'Ticket-ID' : d['Ticket-ID']}, updatedata , upsert = True)
        print "Data Inserted Successfully"
```

my updatedata contains below data:

```
    >>print updatedata 

    >>[{u'Status': u'Closed', u'Lastname+': u'xxxx', u'Assigned To Individual': u'xxxxx', u'StatusAttribute': None, u'Modification Date': u'2016/10/31 17:24:30', u'Creation Date': u'2016/10/31 16:37:40', u'Ticket-ID': 3529, u'Firstname+': u'yyyy', u'Priority': 3, u'Short Description+': u'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy', u'Ticket-Typ': u'Incident', u'Department': u'aaa', u'Remark 2': u'sdf', u'Assigned To Group': u'xyz'}, {u'Status': u'Closed', u'Lastname+': u'abc', u'Assigned To Individual': u'abc', u'StatusAttribute': None, u'Modification Date': u'2016/11/01 16:50:48', u'Creation Date': u'2016/10/31 17:14:59', u'Ticket-ID': 3529, u'Firstname+': u'abc', u'Priority': 3, u'Short Description+': u'xxxxxxxxxxxx', u'Ticket-Typ': u'Incident', u'Department': u'dhdh', u'Remark 2': u'fff', u'Assigned To Group': u'abc'}]
```

i am facing below error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ssrujan\Desktop\CISM\CSVtoMongodb.py", line 119, in <module>
     CSVtoMongodb.import_content(filename,Database,Collection)
   File "C:\Users\ssrujan\Desktop\CISM\CSVtoMongodb.py", line 109, in import_content
db_cm.update_many({'Ticket-ID' : d['Ticket-ID']}, updatedata , upsert = True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 887, in update_many
common.validate_ok_for_update(update)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\common.py", line 413, in validate_ok_for_update
validate_is_mapping("update", update)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\common.py", line 389, in validate_is_mapping
"collections.Mapping" % (option,))
 TypeError: update must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

i am new to mongodb, please help.

Comment: Could you include the source for `fix_dict`? Or better yet, include a minimal example of the data that failed to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `update_many`, use `replace_one`:

```
db_cm.replace_one({'Ticket-ID' : d['Ticket-ID']}, updatedata , upsert=True)
```

For more info consult [the replace_one documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one).